# Generate initial segments of random n-dimensional infinite array in numpy

Tags: numpy, random

Consider the following function:

```
def random_matrix(rows, cols):
    rng = np.random.default_rng(0)
    return rng.random((rows, cols))
```

How can I make a function `f` that makes random matrices like `random_matrix` but has the property that, for all `r1`, `r2`, `c1`, `c2`, `f(r1, c1)[:min(r1, r2), :min(c1, c2)]` is equal to `f(r2, c2)[:min(r1, r2), :min(c1, c2)]`?  (This is the two-dimensional case of the slightly more general question in the title.  The 1-dimensional case is trivial since it is numpy's normal behavior.)

Comment: 'infinite array' does not compute.

Comment: Hi, @hpaulj. Do you meant that you don't understand my question? I tried to make it more concrete in the question details in case the title was unclear

Comment: Why would you need this? Do you know r and c values ahead of time? If so, why not just generate an array once outside the function and then in the function return a slice?

Comment: Obviously I don't know the maximum possible r and c values in advance or I could just return slices, like you say.  In my actual application, I don't need the full power of this functionality, and there is a workaround I can use.  But in the general case, I don't see any performant workaround

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to fill random matrix in the diagonal way, in the spirit of Morton (Z-order) curves
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve

UPDATE

```
import numpy as np
import zCurve as z

def want_mtx(nx: int, ny: int) -> bool:

    index = z.interlace(nx-1, ny-1, dims=2)
    if index+1 == nx*ny:
        return True

    return False
```

Above is simple function which tells you what kind of matrix one could generate using particular z-curve implementation.

E.g., want_mtx(4,2) would return True, meaning you could generate non-square matrix which could be indexed with z-curve. Same for want_mtx(8,4)

So one could generate matrices having overlapping sample

```
def random_matrix(rows, cols):
    rng =  np.random.default_rng(1357531)

    if not want_mtx(cols, rows):
        return None

    index = z.interlace(cols-1, rows-1, dims=2)

    mtx = np.empty((cols, rows))

    for k in range(0, index+1):
        ptidx = z.deinterlace(k, dims=2)
        mtx[ptidx] = rng.random()
    
    return mtx
```

E.g. 4x2 and 8x4 matrices would have 4x2 part the same (as well as 8x8, 16x8 etc)

You could invent your own nd tuple -> linear and inverse functions, after all you know better your domain problem. But it would always be restrictive how are your matrices are laid out, and what dimensions are allowed

Comment: I think if you are implementing the 2-D random matrix from scratch in C, this is not the best approach since you will have to compute numbers you don't need in the case of non-square matrices.  And if you are using just numpy, I don't see an efficient way to reshape a stream of random numbers in this way (you would have to use a for loop)

Comment: You need some immutable walking order to satisfy your conditions. Walking order should be function of indices like Morton curve. What would be optimal order for some (r1,c1) pair would be suboptimal for some other (r2,c2), but I don't see much choice there given constraints. No, it would work for non-square matrices, I had an answer there with something like Morton for non-cubic 3D case. Concerning numpy, you could think about doing this part in C, or check implementations like https://pypi.org/project/zCurve/

Comment: @gmr see also https://mail.python.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2012-November/064558.html If you need, I could dig out my previous answer wrt non-cubic Morton

Comment: I mean, if you want to generate an mxn matrix, with WLOG m>n, using your method you would have to generate mn entries instead of just mn.  It would be better to generate m entries and then use each of those entries as part of the seed of another stream to generate n entries.  Then you would only have to generate mn entries

Comment: "you would have to generate mn entries instead of just mn" you mean mm entries?  Not correct. You could generate non-square matrices. Let me write a bit of code in the update, using Zcurve

Comment: With your approach, you have to fix an ordering of the 2D-array to generate in, but then you could have to generate a larger part of the infinite array than you need and just return a part (or else actually fail to generate arbitrary array shapes like in your example code).  So it would be better to use a 2D random source.  E.g., to generate mxn matrix, you could generate m random numbers, add one to each of these numbers, and use the resulting m numbers as seeds for m streams of random numbers of length n.  But probably you can't do that efficiently in python

Comment: @gmr Yes, I map universal linearization (nD <-> 1D) curve into linear sequence (fixed by seed) of random numbers. Work for all dimensions. If you post your approach as an answer I would take a look